# Unable to add a needed reference in asp.net core class library (IFormFile)

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to write a class library in which I have a model for a file attachments table in the database. My model looks like this (simplified)

```
 public class Attachment : IAuditable
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int ID { set; get; }

        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile formFile { set; get; }

        public string FileName { get; set; } //extension not stored here
        public string FileExt { get; set; }
        public byte[] FileContent { get; set; }
    }
```

A separate attachment table in which I have an IFormFile field to pass to the view (file upload cshtml), get the data back and then write to the FileContent field to save to the database's blob field.

But in a separate class library, I am unable to add a reference to the Microsoft.Aspnetcore.Http which needs to be referenced to the IFormFile variable. I am able to do that only in a web app.

Anyway around this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I figured this out.
I need to run NuGet and install the Aspnetcore to the class library project as well.